# What is the Genre of this Video Game music / what are similar songs?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre

There is a particular musical piece from the video game Final Fantasy 6 called Phantom Train which has me mesmerized today. I would like to ask how the genre of this song might be called.

Link to a rendition on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJeOJ3zcs4E

To me personally the sound evokes a feeling of grandiose decadance combined with morbid melancholy. A kind of bitter-sweet symphony if you will.

Do you know any similar songs to this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **dirge**

> A **dirge** is a somber song or lament expressing mourning or grief, such as would be appropriate for performance at a funeral
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirge

The harpsichord figures give it a **baroque** sound.

> The **Baroque** is a highly ornate and often extravagant style of architecture, music, dance, painting, sculpture and other arts that flourished in Europe from the early 17th until the mid-18th century.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baroque

So what you have here is a **baroque dirge** or **funeral march**.

Examples:

- Purcell - [Queen Mary's Funeral March](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RE44_C50KWY)
- J.H. Roman - [King Frederick's Funeral March](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94SVUZDIqP0)
- Mozart [Requiem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zi8vJ_lMxQI) (technically classical, not baroque)

Here's a more recent song deliberately written in that same style:

- [Ballad of the Harpsichord - Dirge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsgzUyQgCRM)

Answer (score 0):

In the classical world:

Saint-Saens, Danse macabre

Gounod, Funeral March of a Marionette

Liszt, Totentanz

Berlioz, last two movements of Symphonie Fantastique